# How can I check if a user is in any one of a few different roles with MVC4 Simple membership?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I understand that a good way to check if an user is in a role is:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{

}
```

However How can I check if my user is in one of the "Author", "Admin" or "Super" roles? Is there a way to do this **without coding "User.IsInRole" for each of the roles**?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**EDIT: Without coding each role, do it a LINQ extension method, like so:**

```
private static bool IsInAnyRole(this IPrincipal user, List<string> roles)
{
    var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.Identity.Name);

    return userRoles.Any(u => roles.Contains(u));
}
```

For usage, do:

```
var roles = new List<string> { "Admin", "Author", "Super" };

if (user.IsInAnyRole(roles))
{
    //do something
}
```

Or without the extension method:

```
var roles = new List<string> { "Admin", "Author", "Super" };
var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);

if (userRoles.Any(u => roles.Contains(u))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Checking them one by one doesn't sound so efficient to me.  I was thinking if I could use Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name) and then check the result but I am not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: @Melina Check my edit, did it without those In Roles checks :)

Comment: Thanks. That's looks very nice. If I wanted to just do this inline how could I populate the roles list? What's the easy way to do that?

Comment: @Melina No problem, check my updated edit for usages both with and without the extension method.

Comment: @mattytommo +1, very nice. I did have to add the `this` for the extension method (maybe you should edit). i.e. `private static bool IsInAnyRole(this IPrincipal user, List<string> roles)
{` ...

Comment: @rwisch45 Missed that! Updated, thanks for spotting it out :)

Comment: why private  method? is a mistake?

Comment: @sintetico82 Depends where you use it really, for my scenario it could be `private`, but it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 54):

There's no built-in way to check if a user is in multiple roles, but it's pretty trivial to create a nice extension method to handle it for you:

```
public static bool IsInAnyRole(this IPrincipal principal, params string[] roles)
{
    return roles.Any(principal.IsInRole);
}
```

Usage then is:

```
if (User.IsInAnyRole("Admin", "Author", "SuperUser"))
{

}
```

Comment: +1 for reusability... and for beating me to what would have been a pretty much identical answer ;)

Comment: But does this not repeat the User.IsInRole three or more times? I was thinking if I could use Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name) and then check the result but I am not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: There's no efficiency concern here. Whatever you want to do, you have to check to see if a user is in each role, one role at a time. This implementation is "optimistic" and quits early if it matches a role, but the difference it makes is so small, you would have a hard time measuring it.

Comment: the extension method can be shortened to return roles.Any(principal.IsInRole);

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
if(Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName).Contains("Admin")){
}
```

Comment: How to check with this method if an user is in one of the "Author", "Admin" or "Super" roles?

Comment: if(Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName).Contains("Admin") || Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName).Contains("Author") || Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName).Contains("Super") ){ //implement
}

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to elaborate a little on mattytommo's answer, here is what I use:

**Extension Method:**

```
public static bool IsInAnyRole(this IPrincipal user, string[] roles)
        {
            //Check if authenticated first (optional)
            if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return false;
            var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.Identity.Name);
            return userRoles.Any(roles.Contains);
        }
```

**Constants:**

```
public static class Role
{
    public const string Administrator = "Administrator";
    public const string Moderator = "Moderator";
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if (User.IsInAnyRole(new [] {Role.Administrator,Role.Moderator}))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code. In my case, I had a semi colon de-limited string as the parameter which is read from web.config. You may change the below code easily if you are passing a List.

```
public class ActiveDirectoryGroup
{
    public static bool IsInAnyRole(string adRoles)
    {
        return adRoles.Split(Convert.ToChar(";")).Any(role => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(role.Trim()) && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(role.Trim()));
        //If list is passed use below
        //return listParameter.Any(role => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(role.Trim()) && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(role.Trim()));
    }
}
```

In web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ADGroup" value="Domain\Admin;Domain\Supervisor;Domain\Manager;" />
</appSettings>
```

I used it like below in my page load:

```
if (ActiveDirectoryGroup.IsInAnyRole(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADGroup"]))
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use this simple way :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Administrator") || User.IsInRole("Moderator"))
    {
        ... Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what the question is asking to avoid

Comment: This may not be "directly" answering the question but it is very simple and useful to me. + 1 my friend.  It also "indirectly" answers the question by stating that there is no way to do it other than the way that the questioner was trying to avoid. Indeed, sometimes the answer is no, there is no other way. :) Cheers everyone

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just have one role per user. So i did it like this:

```
if (User.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId == "7b433246-5881-4ace-bbaa-e5514191171c") {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should work:

```
 if (User.Roles.Count() != 0)
 {
   //User is not in any role
 } else
 {
   //User is in at least one role
 }
```