# Authorize user actions programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to restrict the access to certain controllers only to logged in Users.

How do I do that. I mean the control should go to login page if the user is not authorized. These users are in a separate table in database.

**EDIT:**

Here is my actual code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidUsers()
    {
        DBContextClass db = new DBContextClass();
        string loginId = Request.Form["LoginId"].ToString();
        string password = Request.Form["Password"].ToString();
        string name = (from user in db.User where user.LoginId.Equals(loginId) && user.Password.Equals(password) select user.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        if (name != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Name = name;
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Admin");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Invalid Login Id or Password, Please try again";
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
}
```

I want give access only to these users to all the controllers except HomeController. How to go about this further?

Comment: Please give details about your actual code and maybe a sample of database. It is easier to say what to add to an existing code than telling you from scratch...

Comment: Here is my controller function to validate users

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add the users and Roles

```html
<authorization>
  <allow users="Kim"/>
  <allow roles="Admins"/>     
  <deny users="John"/> 
  <deny users="?"/>  //that will be anonymous users 
</authorization>
```

Comment: and for checking the user try out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405837/how-to-check-user-is-in-many-roles-in-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `[authorize]` attribute on action methods in controllers or the whole controller classes , It can accept role types , users etc , for more information consult https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396