# find user role in identity asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using this code for login. How can I find a user role when user login?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
            {
                ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on.";
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: By looking into [user.Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151766(v=vs.108).aspx#P:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser`4.Roles) ?

Comment: what are you trying to do, why are you trying to read users roles when uses is logging  in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`user.Roles` will fetch list of Roles user belong to. Based on your requirement you can do something like below

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
        {
            ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on.";
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            if(await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id,"Admin")) //<= Checking Role and redirecting accordingly.
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Based on our discussion if you want to fetch all the roles from database you need to do below

Add `ApplicationRoleManager` class to your IdentityConfig.cs as below

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        return manager;
    } 
}
```

Assign RoleManager to Owin Context, so add below to starup.auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
     // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
        //other code here
}
```

In AccountController.cs add a property

```
    private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Pass it in the Constructor

```
    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager,ApplicationRoleManager roleManager )
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }
```

Once you are done with this you can fetch list of all roles by using
    var roles = RoleManager.Roles;

You can use this as per your requirement.

Comment: how do this ? . . .

Comment: What exactly you trying to find about user roles?

Comment: i need to fetch . when user is login , Find Role for  authoriz . Expamle : When User login Find Role like `Admin`, `SuperAdmin` and redirect to special page

Comment: Updated my answer as per your requirement. I haven't tested it in VS, so there may be some typos.

Comment: thank you man .  but i need to find automatic role not manuel and i write `Admin` or `User`  . i need get roles and compare to role of user then rdirect . how do that ?

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding your question but you can use user.Roles after this logic `var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
    if (user != null)    { ` Or something like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405837/how-to-check-user-is-in-many-roles-in-asp-net-identity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125363/discussion-between-kianoush-and-ravi-a).

Comment: Updated as per our discussion. Hope this helps.