# Where to save admin login information to implement application role manager? (ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity

I'm creating an asp net page on Microsoft visual studios and have azure linked up for database usage.

I'm having some trouble figuring out where and how to save usernames and passwords that I wish to be distinguished as "Admin".

My final objective: I am wanting to hide a dropdown tab of my nav bar if the logged in user is NOT an admin. If the logged in user is an admin, the tab will be available on the user interface.

So, I figured that I would add this code to my current project:
[find user role in identity asp mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959874/find-user-role-in-identity-asp-mvc)

From here, I want to add some kind of "if user is admin" flag/function to the following code (this code is from a .cshtml file). The only way the admin menu should be part of the nav bar is if the current user is Admin. I'm not sure how to go about this. The code is as follows--

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @Html.Partial("_AdminMenuPartial")
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @Html.Partial("_UserMenuPartial")
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
```

I'm also not sure where to save Admin login information (username and password) so that when this is all carried out, my code can distinguish if the user is an Admin or not based on if their credentials match up.

Can someone help me with this please? I'm hoping I'm on the right track...

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

  @if (User.IsInRole("Admin") {

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @Html.Partial("_AdminMenuPartial")
    </ul>

  }

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @Html.Partial("_UserMenuPartial")
    </ul>
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```