# Simplify User.IsInRole() check asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In our asp.net mvc project in .cshtml views often you can find:

`if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Supervisor"))`

I'd like to simplify current syntax like this:
`if (IsAdminOrSupervisor(User))`

So, I need to make a html-helper, or some backend helper. Could you help me how can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check user is in many roles in asp.net identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405837/how-to-check-user-is-in-many-roles-in-asp-net-identity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an extension to your identity for checking multiple roles:

```
public static bool IsAdminOrSupervisor(this IPrincipal user, List<string> roles)
{
    var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.Identity.Name);

    return userRoles.Any(u => roles.Contains(u));
}
```

Then you can use this like:

```
var roles = new List<string> { "Admin", "Supervisor" };

if (User.IsAdminOrSupervisor(roles))
{
   //Action
}
```

Tips: You need to reference the class that holds this method to your Razor:

```
@Using NameSpace.ClassName
```