# Button permission for identity 2.0 mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, asp.net-identity

I have implemented default identity2.0 for my mvc5 project. How can i disable an Action Link which renders a partialview(Ex: Create partialview) restricting the access of that partial view for an unauthorized user.

I can put the authorization attribute on the save action method. But i want to restrict the access of the partial view by disabling the Action Link which renders that partial view. To further demonstrate my question i have put the code below.

This is the save action method

```
    CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Save(ProductType producttype)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //
            objContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("vwProductTypeIndex");
        }
    }
```

_Create Partial view with Save button

```
 @Html.BeginForm("Save", "ProductType"))
 {
     //
     <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" clientidmode="Static">
 }
```

I want to disable the below Action Link (Add New Record) which is a button decorated with css which renders the above partial view.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add New Record", "vwProductTypeIndex", "ProductType", new { A = "New" }, new { Class = "btn btn-primary page-scroll", style = "top:50px; margin-left:168px;width:120px;text-indent:-5px; position:relative;" })
```

How can i achieve this. All help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the role with the UserManager.IsInRole(userId,"Role") where UserManager is HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(). You may want to create a helper method to make this easier to access.

Now you can use this directly in Razor or you could use it in the Get side of your controller to build a viewmodel or ViewBag setting.

So your code would end up looking something like:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Could you please provide me an example for your explanation or a link. Because i have no idea of how to approach it. Pls guide me..

Comment: @ Steve Greene, Thanks.. Im going to study it. If i have any questions i'll ask from you..

Comment: @ Steve Greene, Thanks a lot. User.IsInRole("//") works fine in my views. But i have another question. If i have to check for many roles then i have to do it like this.  @if(User.IsInRole("Admin")||User.IsInRole("Manager")||///////).    How can i avoid getting this long. Could you please suggest me a solution for it?

Comment: There are a few options. If you have a common group you use, you could just create a helper function like "IsManager" "HasAdminAccess" then do the check there: return User.IsInRole("Admin")||User.IsInRole("Manager")||.. Then your controller of view code would be @if (SecurityHelper.IsManager())... If the number of groups is large and you're going to be checking them in different combinations, then I would create an extension method as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477757/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-is-in-any-one-of-a-few-different-roles-with-mvc4-simpl