# Check user rank

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to get my user ranking, so that if the user ranking is == to admin, it will show `this text` and if it is in mod it wil show `this text`. I have tryed doing:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <b>I'm a mod!</b>
            }
```

But that won't work because, that will only show IF your are in the role Admin when your looking.

So how should i make it so that a `Normal` user who enter that page can see a message, that depends on wich rank the user is in.

Comment: you have to explicitly declare the roles you want to be able to see the message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a user is in any one of a few different roles with MVC4 Simple membership?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477757/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-is-in-any-one-of-a-few-different-roles-with-mvc4-simpl)

Comment: @user1666620 I'm aware of that, but not sure how to do it!

Comment: check the duplicate link

Comment: @user1666620 I'm not looking for a backend way, i need it just in my view.

Comment: that is also in the answer of the duplicate link

Comment: And that question is not the same as mine... @user1666620

Comment: then can you try to explain your question more clearly. i thought you wanted to show certain text if a user was one of several roles.